# List of open conjectures on fractals

Tags: reference-request, big-list, fractals

I want a list of open conjectures on fractals.

Preferably easy to understand and low dimensions.

Before you say Eremenko's conjecture ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escaping_set ):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.10256.pdf

claims a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The MLC conjecture: the Mandelbrot set is locally connected. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Local_connectivity) for the statement and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95701/the-deep-significance-of-the-question-of-the-mandelbrot-sets-local-connectednes) for discussion of its significance. For a popular discussion, see [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-quest-to-decode-the-mandelbrot-set-maths-famed-fractal-20240126/?mc_cid=7b8025d489&mc_eid=43bb321af6).

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09869.pdf) relates MLC to other conjectures, stated as the Density of Hyperbolicity Conjecture, the Rigidity Conjecture, the No Invariant Line Fields Conjecture, and the Triviality of Fibers Conjecture.